# How can I Use JpaSpecificationExecutor from Spring-Jpa without transaction

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvVje.jpg)When I using JpaSpecificationExecutor doing findAll, I found it 
automatically adding transaction, starting sql with

set autocommit = 0;

And I don't want it.

I test JpaRepository, doing the same select sql and it didn't go with
set autocommit = 0;

but the JpaSpecificationExecutor has.

Then I break point it and find out there is a PROXY do that adding transaction thing, but I don't know how to disable it.

I do set defaultAutoCommit: true

And I also set

```
datasource:

  tomcat:

    default-auto-commit: true

  dbcp2:

    default-auto-commit: true
```

the connection pool is already defaultAutoCommit=true

it didn't help

so I blame the JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<GameEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<GameEntity> {
    List<GameEntity> findByName(String name);
}
```

```
public List<GameEntity> search(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return mGameRepository.findAll(searchAction(request), new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
    }
```

[break point screen cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvVje.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all the CRUD methods (CrudRepository methods) are by default marked as transactional.

But how can I unmark it?

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories has an attribute enableDefaultTransactions defaulting to true. If you disable this, Spring Data assumes you're manually taking care of transactions required by JPA.       ---  this is from Oliver Drotbohm